# Multiple producer single consumer - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, producer-consumer

I want to solve the multiple producer single consumer problem and, the following code shows one producer and one consumer thread in an infinite while loop, (I did this to test my code) but it gives wrong data output and then a segmentation fault after some time this is the code i tried:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<thread>
#include<assert.h>

#define QUEUE_SIZE 100

using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
};
template<class T, unsigned long Q_SIZE = QUEUE_SIZE>
class NaiveQueue {
private:
    static const unsigned long Q_MASK = Q_SIZE - 1;
    unsigned long head_, tail_;
    std::condition_variable cond_empty_;
    std::condition_variable cond_overflow_;
    std::mutex mtx_;
    T **ptr_array_;

public:
    NaiveQueue(): head_(0), tail_(0)
    {
        ptr_array_ = (T **)::memalign(getpagesize(),Q_SIZE * sizeof(void *));
        assert(ptr_array_);
    }

    void push(T *x)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
        cond_overflow_.wait(lock, [this]() {
                    return tail_ + Q_SIZE > head_;
                });
        ptr_array_[head_++ & Q_MASK] = x;
        cond_empty_.notify_one();
    }

    T* pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
        cond_empty_.wait(lock, [this]() {
                    return tail_ < head_;
                });
        T *x = ptr_array_[tail_++ & Q_MASK];
        cond_overflow_.notify_one();
        return x;
    }
};
void producer(NaiveQueue<node> &obj)
{
    while(1)
    {
    node *temp;
    temp=new node();
    temp->data=10;
    obj.push(temp);
    cout<<"\nPushed : "<<10;
    }
}
void consumer(NaiveQueue<node> &obj)
{
    while(1)
    {
    node *temp;
    temp=NULL;
    temp=obj.pop();
    if(temp)
    {
        cout<<"\nRemoved : "<<temp->data;
        delete temp;
    }
    }
}
int main()
{
    NaiveQueue<node> obj;
    thread t1(producer,ref(obj));   
    thread c1(consumer,ref(obj));
    t1.join();
    c1.join();  
    return 0;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
Pushed : 
Removed : 1010
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 
Removed : 1010
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : 10
Removed : -1140848048
Removed : -1140847792
Removed : -1140847760
Removed : -1140847856
Removed : -1140847824
Removed : -1140847792
Removed : -1140847760
Removed : -1140847856
Removed : -1140847824
Removed : -1140847792
Removed : -1140847760
Removed : -1140847856
Removed : -1140847824
Removed : -1140847792
Removed : -1140847760
Removed : -1140847856
Removed : -1140847824
Removed : -1140847792
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 
Removed : 1010
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Pushed : 10
Segmentation fault
```

Where did I go wrong? Why is `-1140847856` being removed when it wasn't pushsed at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your waiting condition and index calculation is wrong:

Let

```
Q_SIZE =10, Q_MASK=9, tail_=2,head_=5
```

then

```
tail_ + Q_SIZE > head_
```

will be true and it will push

```
head_++ & Q_MASK = 5 & 9 = 1th index
```

which is wrong.

When

```
tail_=0, head_= 9
```

then 
`tail_ + Q_SIZE > head_`
will be true and it will push

```
head_++ & Q_MASK = 9 & 9 = 9th index
```

But the queue is full, and the push should have waited until `tail_` becomes `1`, i.e at least one items is popped.

Also `tail_ < head_` is wrong condition when popping.

Roughly you can do this (not tested)

```
void push(T *x)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
    cond_overflow_.wait(lock, [this]() {
                return abs( head_ - tail_ )< Q_SIZE ;
            });
    ptr_array_[head_ ] = x;
    head_ = (++head) % Q_SIZE;
    cond_empty_.notify_one();
}

T* pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
    cond_empty_.wait(lock, [this]() {
                return abs(head_ - tail_)>0;
            });
    T *x = ptr_array_[tail_];
    tail_ = (++tail_)% Q_SIZE;
    cond_overflow_.notify_one();
    return x;
}
```

Comment: How to fix? Suggest changes please. Should I change them to Mod ?

Comment: It works for by dong mod and maintaing number of elements in Queue separately... Is it ok to do so?

Comment: Any suggestions for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589828/locking-in-multiple-producer-single-consumer

Comment: Hi @Superman, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider 
[accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some
reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.