# Locking in Multiple producer single consumer

Tags: c++, producer-consumer

I am trying to solve a multiple producer single consumer problem with the producers generating integers and the consumer making a sorted list out of all these integers(using AVL tree). How should I be locking my tree data structure? Or is it unnecessary? The queue has proper locking for push and pop operations.

```
void consumer(NaiveQueue<nodeQ> &obj)
{
    while(1)
    {
    nodeQ *temp;
    temp=NULL;
    temp=obj.pop();
    if(temp)
      {
        cout << "\nRemoved : " << temp->data;
        root=insert(root,temp->data); //****lock this??????
        delete temp;
      }
   }  
}
```

Producer(Multithreaded producers => threads made in main):

```
void makeChildThread(int &newsockfd,char msg[MAXSZ],NaiveQueue<nodeQ> &obj)
{
   //receive from client
   while(1)
   {
    int n=recv(newsockfd,msg,MAXSZ,0);
    if(n==0)
    {
     close(newsockfd);
     break;
    }
    //msg[n]=0;
    //send(newsockfd,msg,n,0);
    int val=atoi(msg);
    if(val == 0)
    {
        break;
        exit(0);
    }

    nodeQ *temp;
    temp=new nodeQ();
    temp->data=val;
    obj.push(temp);
    cout<<"\nPushed : "<<val;

    cout<<"\nReceived :"<<msg;
   }//close while
    cout<<"\nExit from thread";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the queue will be accessed by all producers and consumer, the access needs to synchronize. But if the tree is used by the **single** consumer, why lock it? Locking is unnecessary and will cause extra overhead.